# Kotlin instanceOf Iterable

Tags: java, kotlin

I want to verify that Any is Iterable

```
 override fun funnyFunction(context: Any): Any {
       if(context is Iterable)
         // do something
}
```

Warning that i get is

> One type argument expected. Use 'Iterable<*>' if you don't want to
> pass type arguments

In Java the code is

```
 Object funnyFunction(final context: Object) {
           if(context instanceof Iterable)
             // do something
 }
```

Anyone have idea how to do it?

Answer (score 4):

It tells you exactly what to do.  You need to write

```
if (context is Iterable<*>)
```

Just because Java does it differently doesn't mean Kotlin does it that way.

Comment: Mmm. In Java, `Iterable` is a [raw type](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/rawTypes.html) — an awkward hack left in the language in order to support decades-old code from before generics were added to the language. Kotlin had generics from the start, so doesn't need raw types. (OTOH, it still has to deal with the fall-out from type erasure, another of Java's questionable decisions…)